# Repeatedly getting Software lockout in OpenSUSE

Tags: linux, gnome, opensuse

So I recently installed OpenSUSE and whenever I try to install new software, I get the following Error:

*System management is locked by the application with pid xxxx (/usr/bin/ruby).
Close this application before trying again.*

I am aware that ruby is a programming language but whenever I google this, I don't get squat. So I got around this by doing kill -9 xxxx but it then comes back in a minute or two. Also when I kill the process the background goes away and I am left with black, something similar to how in Windows when you kill the explorer.exe. I have no idea why this is happening. Any tips in the right direction is helpful, thank you.